# Jade template: How to create a hyperlink in UL with description to the hyperlink

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm trying to create a list with hyperlinks. Each list item contains a subject and a simple description to that subject in one line. I want to include a hyperlink for the subject but not the description. What I did is as below.

```
ul#subjects
    li
        a(href="#") Subject: Here is the description of the subject
```

The link works fine but it covers the whole line of text. How do I close the hyperlink so that it becomes something like below in HTML? Note that the ':' is not covered by the hyperlink.

```
<ul id='subjects'>
    <li><a href='#'>Subject</a>: Here is is the description of the subject
</ul>
```

Thank you. : )

Comment: for future reference a good tool: http://html2jade.org/

Comment: Wow, nice tool, man. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `|` to display the HTML text in Jade

e.g.

```
ul#subjects
  li
    a(href="#") Subject
    | : Here is the description of the subject
```